# DLL reference not working in Visual Studio VB?

Tags: vb.net

So I have a fairly simple application that i found originally in C# I converted it to VB and everything is working perfectly find all the system references are working fine but this one DLL (gameserverinfo.dll) is not being found. I have re-added the reference in Project > Add reference and I have also changed the location of the dll and still no go. I'm not sure why it is having an issue as i have referenced it in other projects and had no issues. And thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing a namespace.  Try importing the namespace at the beginning of the file, fully qualifying any method/classes, or adding a global import statement from the reference page of the project properties.